# Can't install newer NVIDIA display driver on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm using Windows 7, and the latest version of NVIDIA display driver I can install on my computer is 275.33 (or 266.58, I can't decide now, see below).

When installing newer version of the driver (e.g. 275.50 and 280.26), the installer always fails at "Installing NVIDIA Control Panel", then Windows 7 reverts to 275.33 (the newest stock version?).

I tried to find installation logs but couldn't find it. I tried to completely delete (in fact I renamed) `c:\progra~1\nvidia~1` folder but still couldn't install.

How to resolve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What GPU are you using.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue not to long ago.  Uninstall your current version of the NVidia driver and reboot.  If WIndows starts hardware detection on boot, cancel out of it.  Then right click the current installer and run as administrator.